# Is a DSL splitter required, if only a Modem is attached to the line?

Tags: modem, dsl, splitter

Annex B is the current standard for digital subscriber line (DSL) in Germany. A [DSL-splitter](http://www.badenhausen.com/it-systems/docs/E47.2012_ADSL-VDSL-Splitter.pdf) is an analog L-C-filter to separate the POTS (plain old telephone service, like voice and ISDN, FAX) signals from the DSL signal.

**Is the DSL-splitter required, if no devices but a DSL-Modem is connected to the line?**

If yes, one could test if a splitter is faulty by connecting the Modem direct to the line. The bandwidth should be similar in both situations.

Comment: No splitter or filter needed.

Comment: The answers are in contradiction. Can you please provide sources?

Comment: Is the situation different, if the line provides Annex A instead of Annex B?

Comment: From https://community.linksys.com/t5/Cable-and-DSL/What-is-Annex-B-amp-Annex-A-on-the-WAG54G/td-p/23371 "Annex A is ADSL used in most of North America and Europe where the telephone line carries voice and ADSL. As far as I know Annex B is only used in Germany where they have have voice, ISDN and ADSL on the same line."

Answer (score 8):

A DSL filter performs 2 functions:

1. To prevent DSL frequencies from reaching non-DSL devices
2. To prevent spurious noise from non-DSL devices from interfering with DSL frequencies

If there are no non-DSL devices on the line then no filter is required.

Comment: Indeed, my provider (XS4ALL, The Netherlands, FRITZ!Box 7360) explicitly asked me to remove the splitter for a situation where only (V)DSL is used, without any analogue telephony. I'm not sure if the type of modem matters.

Comment: Can you provide a good source for this statement? Some devices have a splitter/filter included. Hence a simple report of personal experience is not so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Reference [ADSL Filters & Splitters](http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/splitters.htm)

You should use a filter anyway. The filter performs two main functions:

1. Prevents the ADSL signal interfering with the voice part of your phone line (not required in your case as you have no phone connected)
2. **Ensures that the ADSL line is terminated correctly. An unmatched termination may cause reflections back down the line. This can cause errors on the ADSL connection.**

Comment: My provider (XS4ALL, The Netherlands, FRITZ!Box 7360) explicitly asked me to remove the splitter for a situation where only (V)DSL is used, without any analogue telephony. It might be different for other modems?

Comment: The reference is very informative. It seems that the DSL hardware used in UK is very different from that in DE.

Comment: @JonasStein *DSL splitters are basically ultra low tech devices with very few components. They can be designed pretty much any way.

Comment: @DanielB For example: I have not seen a DSL Y-connector for two ADSL MoDeMs on one line as shown on this UK website in germany before. And in UK only 4 kHz seem to be reserved. Perhaps Annex B?

Comment: @JonasStein I don’t see any Y-connector on that page. Except in Germany, everyone is using Annex A (“ADSL over POTS”) whenever possible, because it’s superior in range and speed. Since ISDN isn’t all that popular world-wide, Annex B (“ADSL over ISDN”) is rather uncommon.

Comment: @DanielB I think the `BT Doubler` on http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/splitter_install.htm could be a kind of Y-connector.

Comment: @JonasStein BT Doubler - "This instant plug in adaptor from BT, allows you the freedom to convert a single BT socket to a double (2 way) outlet." so it converts 1 telephone socket into 2 (http://www.shop.bt.com/products/bt-socket-doubler-4KQT.html)